# How can I get recursive query of data from a data table?

Tags: google-sheets, recursive-query

I have this table of values:

| Item | Date | Cost | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1/1/2019 | $100 |  |
| Item2 | 1/2/2019 | $101 |  |
| Item3 | 1/3/2019 | $102 |  |
| Item2 | 1/1/2019 | $150 |  |
| Item1 | 1/2/2019 | $151 |  |
| Item3 | 1/3/2019 | $152 |  |
| Item1 | 1/1/2019 | $200 |  |
| Item2 | 1/2/2019 | $201 |  |
| Item2 | 1/3/2019 | $202 |  |

When I use `Query` to organize the values I get this:

| Item | Date | Cost | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1/1/2019 | $100 |  |
| Item1 | 1/2/2019 | $151 |  |
| Item1 | 1/1/2019 | $200 |  |
| Item2 | 1/2/2019 | $101 |  |
| Item2 | 1/1/2019 | $150 |  |
| Item2 | 1/2/2019 | $201 |  |
| Item2 | 1/3/2019 | $202 |  |
| Item3 | 1/3/2019 | $102 |  |
| Item3 | 1/3/2019 | $152 |  |

However, I'd like to get a header for the item and a query of the other columns that matches that header as shown below (to make it easier to read in a report form):

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 |  |  |
| Date | Cost | Notes |
| 1/1/2019 | $100 |  |
| 1/2/2019 | $151 |  |
| 1/1/2019 | $200 |  |
| Item 2 |  |  |
| Date | Cost | Notes |
| 1/2/2019 | $101 |  |
| 1/1/2019 | $150 |  |
| 1/2/2019 | $201 |  |
| 1/3/2019 | $202 |  |

PS: Please note the original table have over 500 items and each have about 20 to 30 entries.

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

I tried tried using the following in Google Sheets:

`query` = can not get recursive query to get the header in a line above.
`byRow+lambda` = can not have more than one line of results per row.
`map+lambda` = could not understand how to get this one to work

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(c,,),B1:D1,filter(B:D,A:A=c))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 
I did not think this was possible in a Spreadsheet

However could you explain: tocol(,1)  

Is it missing a value before the ','?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to do this in Excel this is the formula that works in my sheet.

=DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A2:A10),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,c,B1:D1,FILTER(B2:D10,A2:A10=c)))),""),1)

The data is in range A2:A10 (Item) and B2:B10 (Date) and C2:C10 (Cost) and D2:D10 (Notes).